# TSQL Pivot with strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, pivot

My apologies, as I know this is a question that's been answered many times in various contexts. However, after an hour of trying and failing to adapt the examples I've found to my needs, I'm at the conclusion that I'm an idiot, and need help specific to my data...

I have a view that returns data as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM vwPersonMainContactDetails
```

Output:

```
PersonID  | ContactMethod   | ContactValue
----------+-----------------+-----------------
1           Email             Bob@abc.com
1           Mobile            07777 777777
2           Email             kate@abc.com
2           Mobile            07766 666666
3           Email             jo@abc.com
3           Mobile            07755 555555
```

What I need is to return the data structured as follows:

```
PersonID  |  Mobile        |  Email
----------+----------------+--------------------------
1            07777 777777     bob@abc.com
2            07766 666666     kate@abc.com
3            07755 555555     jo@abc.com
```

Can anyone help? I know that PIVOT will be the answer, but I'm really struggling to make it work for me...

Thanks a lot

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005+ you can do this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
SELECT
    PersonID,
    ContactMethod,
    ContactValue
FROM
    vwPersonMainContactDetails
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(ContactValue)
    FOR ContactMethod IN ([Email],[Mobile])
) AS pvt
```

If you are not using mssql you can do this:

```
SELECT
    PersonID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ContactMethod='Mobile' THEN ContactValue ELSE NULL END) AS Mobile,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ContactMethod='Email' THEN ContactValue ELSE NULL END) AS Email
FROM
    vwPersonMainContactDetails
GROUP BY
    PersonID
```

**Reference:**

- [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you both for your help - it's much appreciate.

Comment: Okay - finally, it's working. Thanks to both of you for your help - both your solutions worked perfectly, so I've given the vote to Arion for providing two solutions, but thanks also to Deepshikha for the explanations. It wasn't working earlier (as per my first comment) because I'd forgotten when I originally posted that the column names include Hungarian prefixes, so were lngPersonID, strContactMethod and strContactValue. As I'd forgotten to mention them, they weren't mentioned in your solutions (funnily enough!). But once I'd added the prefixes, both solutions were great.

Comment: The moral of the story is never post questions when in a desperate rush to get out the door to a meeting!

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the syntax for Pivot:

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,
    ...
    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>
FROM
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)
    AS <alias for the source query>
PIVOT
(
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)
FOR
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],
    ... [last pivoted column])
) AS <alias for the pivot table>
<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

1. Aggregate function in this case can be: `max/min`
2. column being aggregated :`ContactValue`  = `Email` and `Mobile`
3. Now in Pivot all columns that are left in source table (here T)are considered for grouping and in this case it will be PersonID so Pivot becomes:

   `SELECT PersonID, -- <non-pivoted column>,
   Mobile , --[first pivoted column] AS <column name>,
   Email--[second pivoted column] AS <column name>,
   FROM
       (
       SELECT PersonID ,ContactValue,ContactMethod 
       from vwPersonMainContactDetails)-- query that produces the data>)
       AS T --<alias for the source query>
   PIVOT
   (
       max(ContactValue) --<aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)
       FOR [ContactMethod] --<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]
       IN ( [Mobile],[Email]--[first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],
   )
   )as pvt
   order by PersonID asc
   --<optional ORDER BY clause>;`
   <kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/IDQQ24885)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Another way for readability:

```
SELECT PersonID, [Email], [Mobile]
FROM [TABLE]
PIVOT (MAX(ContactValue) FOR ContactMethod IN ([Email], [Mobile])) AS PIV
```

Comment: Hi both, and thank you for your responses. I'm struggling, however, as I'm getting the same response whichever method I try: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'PersonID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'ContactMethod'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'ContactValue'. (PS - Also struggling with getting this comment formatted - sorry!)  . Is it relevant that I'm using SQL Azure?

Comment: I've tested this so it should fit your needs. What's the issue?